# How to disable a section in html using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a section like the image below,

[image: I have]

After clicking the "I am currently working" I want to disable the section below. I don't want to remove the section, I just want to dim and disable the section. How can I do that using html and jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/qwy68g0t/)

The `change` event listens for changes on checkbox, which I specified with the `"#checkbox"`. It's important to use `change` so you are able to toggle the `disable` attribute.

`.attr("disabled", true);` adds the `disabled` attribute. False does the opposite.

```js
$("#checkbox").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        $("#end-month").attr("disabled", true);
    } else {
     $("#end-month").attr("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox">
<label for="checkbox">I am currently working here</label>

<br>

<select id="end-month">
  <option value="date">date</option>
  <option value="another-date">another date</option>
</select>
```

Comment: post some explanation to your answer

Comment: I added explanation to the answer

Comment: `$("#end-month").attr("disabled", this.checked);` ? :)

Answer (score 1):

Disable all elements inside id which is in data-disable attribute. if you wanna hide, use commented code instead dest.attr().

```js
$("input[type='checkbox'][data-disable]").on("click", function () {
  var dest = $("#" + $(this).data("disable")).find(":input");
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    dest.attr("disabled", "disabled");
    //dest.hide();
  } else {
    dest.attr("disabled", false);
    //dest.show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-disable="idToHide"/> Disable</label>
    <div id="idToHide">
        <select><option>test</option></select>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Unable to toggle it off. EDIT: Works now, gj

Comment: corrected was 2 times dest.attr("disabled", "disabled");

Answer (score -1):

The solution doesn't have to be jQuery if you are using forms and inputs, you can just add a `disabled` attribute to the inputs.

https://codepen.io/limxz/pen/XQdPXO

Here are some reference materials.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_disabled.asp

This is a simplified demo without jQuery

```
var checkboxInput = document.querySelector("#checkbox-input");
var dropdownInput = document.querySelector("#dropdown-input");

checkboxInput.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (checkboxInput.value) {
    dropdownInput.setAttribute("disabled", "");
  }
});
```

Comment: Unable to toggle it on again

Comment: You can just do a `dropdownInput.removeAttribute("disabled");` when you need to enable it


https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute